# Does TaskExecutorPartitionHandler uses data grid?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd

I am using step partitioning  in my batch job which is deployed in a distributed Spring XD environment. I would like to know if TaskExecutorPartitionHandler uses data transport in our case is Rabbit MQ?

```
<bean id="itemReader"
    class="sample.ItemReader"
    scope="step"  >
    <property name=requestList"
        value="#{stepExecutionContext[test]}" />
</bean>

<bean id="taskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="15" />
    <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true" />
</bean>
<batch:job id='partitionJob' restartable="false"
    incrementer="jobParametersIncrementerImpl" >
    <batch:step id="startLoopStep">
        <batch:tasklet ref="initTasklet" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id='partitionerStep'>
        <batch:partition step="slave" partitioner="rangePartitioner">
            <batch:handler grid-size="${gridSize}" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
<batch:step id="slave">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter"
            commit-interval="1" retry-limit="3" >
        </batch:chunk>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The `TaskExecutorPartitionHandler` uses local threads to do the partitioning.  The `MessageChannelPartitionHandler` is what you want for distributed partitioning.  Spring XD comes with a context file that you can import for adding partitioning to single step jobs easily.  Most of the out of the box jobs within Spring XD utilize this functionality and can serve as a reference.

Comment: I am seeing step execution objects  in MQ . Would that be because I am using wrong config for step execution context ?

Comment: No.  Spring XD automatically broadcasts the various batch events (including step start/finish) so that other streams can interact with them.  It may be something related to that.